# tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_loss available

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data

I saw that there were similar questions asked with val_acc not shown available. I have tried the solutions listed for that case.

I mean I checked the keys in the history and 'val_loss' exists as one of the keys. I'm also passing a validation data, so it's not raising the error due to validation data not being passed in. Note: I was using 1000 epoches before, I'm justing using 1 right now to test quickly. No matter what I did, I can't seem to make my model learn and it raises the error mentioned the title over and over again at each step. I'm relatively new with Keras, so I wanted to ask if anything strikes to you guys as wrong in below implementation. If not, I would appreciate any help with possible reasons that could be causing the issue.

```
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("rcnn_model", monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq=1)
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=100, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    trdata = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=90)
    traindata = trdata.flow(x=datasets.train_X, y=datasets.train_Y)
    tsdata = ImageDataGenerator(horizontal_flip=True, vertical_flip=True, rotation_range=90)
    testdata = tsdata.flow(x=datasets.test_X, y=datasets.test_Y)

    hist = model.fit_generator(generator= traindata, steps_per_epoch= 10, epochs= 1, validation_data= testdata, validation_steps=2, callbacks=[checkpoint,early_stop])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to stop training at a certain acc,You can stop training the model as the val.acc raise to a point that you define by typing this code:

```
Class MyCallBack(tensorflow.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if(logs.get("val_accuracy")>0.95): # you can change the value
            self.model.stop_training=True

Newcb = MyCallBack()
```

Then use the variable assigned to the class as a callback in model.fit.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Oh sorry if it wasn't clear. I meant that I'm getting an error stating that val_loss is not available, so the weights don't get saved.